# Jqueryui dialog not opening with correct height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a website and for some reason the jqueryui dialog is opening at a height 100px smaller than it should be, if i run the same code in the chrome console, it works fine $("#dlgAddWorkLog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 258, height: 250});

I just updated the latest jqueryui (on the test server) to see if that would fix it, but no avail.

To see the problem in action, go to https://cworklog.com log in as test116 test116 and click "Add Work Log"

The resulting dialog that comes up is about 100px smaller than it should be.

Go ahead and open the console and type 
$("#dlgAddWorkLog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 258, height: 250});

and watch it work flawlessly

I don't know if there is a library collision or what, i'm also using YUI 2.9 on the page as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126000)

Comment: Have you tried option height : 'auto' ?

Comment: yes height: 'auto' or simply leaving out the height does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work_log.php line 350, I am sure that you won't set the height value to 180 px :

```
<select name="company_id" onchange="
   if (this.value == 'new')
   { 
       $('#new_company').toggle(true); 
       $('#dlgAddWorkLog').dialog('option', 'height', 425); }
   else
   { 
       $('#new_company').toggle(false); 
       $('#dlgAddWorkLog').dialog('option', 'height', 180); 
   }
">
```

Avoid JS inline BTW, it is a mess to debug...